# Individual Gradient Fill with Facet Wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to achieve an output where the fill gradient is independent on each histogram. I know I could make individual plots and then combine them using grid.arrange, but I want this to work on a data set with any number of columns.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I would include an image but I don't have the reputation points.

```
# rm(list=ls())

var_his <- function(this_data){
    this_data <- melt(this_data)
    ggplot(this_data, aes(x = value)) + 
        geom_histogram(aes(x = value, y = ..density.., fill = ..count..), position="identity") +  
        facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free") +
        scale_fill_gradient('count', low='lightblue', high='steelblue')
}

data(Seatbelts)
data <- data.frame(Seatbelts)
var_his(data)
```

Comment: Don't put `rm(list=ls())` in sample code on SO. Many of the people who are likely to try to help you have working sessions, which that code will wipe out. This is why I commented it out, but really it should not be there at all.

Comment: You can only really have one fill color scale (there will only be one legend with one set of values). You could scale all of your data to the 0/1 range or something if you want to be able to compare relative frequencies, otherwise you won't have much luck trying to redefine a scale for each facet.